# C++ how to emulate a function without implicit conversions?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to use a function template (or some other templatized construction) to emulate a function without implicit conversions applied to either the arguments or the return expression. What's the most robust way to do this?

Ideally, I'm trying to come up with a way to do this that's easy to hide behind a template or a macro, has decent error messages, and doesn't impose a runtime penalty.

This is intended as a metaprogramming exercise; I'm not going to be doing this in production code.

The function below, `func1` takes two `longs` and adds them together, performing conversions as usual.

```
long func1(long a, long b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

I'd like to define `func` in such a way that `a` and `b` can only be `long`s and check at compile time that the `return` expression really does have the indicated type without an implicit conversion being inserted.

For the sake of concreteness, I've tried to do this a couple of ways so far, and here they are.

One way of preventing conversions (for the arguments only) is to use a function template with a deleted implementation and a specialization for the combination of arguments.

```
template <class L1, class L2>
long func2(L1 a, L2 b) = delete;

template<>
long func2(long a, long b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

It's also possible to use `enable_if` to accomplish the same thing.

```
template <class L1, class L2>
std::enable_if_t<
  std::is_same<L1, long>::value && std::is_same<L2, long>::value
, long> func3(L1 a, L2 b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to incorporate an assertion about the return type without costing myself a copy or a move, or needing to do complex things to strip CV qualification and ref-ness.

```
// doesn't work, unnecessary copy
template <class L1, class L2>
std::enable_if_t<
  std::is_same<L1,long>::value && std::is_same<L2,long>::value,
long> func4(L1 a, L2 b) {
  auto out = a + b;
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(out), long>::value);
  return out;
}
```

I can, however, move the function body into a lambda and then use `static_assert`s to list all the conditions I want. I'm a little concerned that this approach does something surprising.

```
template <class L1, class L2>
long func5(L1 a, L2 b) {
  static auto wrapped = [&](){
    return a + b;
  };
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a), long>::value);
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(b), long>::value);
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(wrapped()), long>::value);
  return wrapped();
}
```

Comment: You might want `-> decltype(auto)` to avoid to loose reference in your check.

Comment: What do you want to do about const-volatile qualifiers? Allow or disallow?

Comment: @JiveDadson That's ... actually a pretty serious oversight in my question. I think I want to disallow it. Usually I don't bother to add `const` to by-value parameters and I didn't think of it.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Especially you are using `long` as an example, for which copy is meaningless. And the example you marked as "unnecessary copy" has no unnecessary copy because of RVO. Anyway, RVO is determined by first removing cv-qualifier, I don't know why you mention those qualifiers.

Comment: @liliscent Sorry, I used `long` in this example because it's most the prototypical example type I can think of that has an implicit conversion you sometimes don't want. I'm intending the various strategies for creating a non-converting pseudo-function to be applied to arbitrary functions (and possibly hidden behind a macro), so it's important that I not make assumptions about the underlying type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably a lot of ways to do this.  Here's one. I don't think there's any reason to check all those cases.  What do you want to do about const-volatile qualifiers? Allow or disallow?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Long>
Long func1(Long a, Long b) {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Long, long>);
    return a + b;
}
int main()
{
    long a = 1;
    const long b = 2;
    const long &c = a;
    std::cout << func1(c,b) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the check mark. Still saving up for that toaster oven.

Comment: How does that ensure that the arguments or the return value are not converted?

Comment: @Walter - You mean something like `func1(1L, static_cast<long>(double_var))`? It doesn't, it can't, and it shouldn't.  I do not know why OP wants to make the restriction, but in C/C++ there is no way to stymie a fellow programmer who insists on shooting his foot.

Comment: The `static_cast` in the above example is what I want to force people to do since it makes the conversion explicit. It (theoretically) makes the user/reviewer/whomever think about whether the conversion is the right thing to do here.

Comment: What about `func1(long(0),1)`? Will this compile? In case of `long`, the built-in `operator+` returns `long`, but in general, there is no guarantee that the result of adding to identical types obtains the same type again. So, in your `func1`, the result of `a+b` may differ from `Long`.

Comment: @Walter - See Gregory's comment. Gregory, no need to @ me. It's my answer so I get buzzed anyway.

Comment: @Walter, think it out. Or try to get the function to return something other than `long`. Comments are not for this kind of discussion.

Comment: ?? Which comment of him do you think addresses which point in my previous comment?

Comment: @Walter - Read all one of them and figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

No need of lambda:

```
template <class L1, class L2>
long func2(L1, L2) = delete;

decltype(auto) func2(long a, long b) {
  return a + b;
}

static_assert(std::is_same<long, decltype(func2(42L, std::declval<long>()))>::value);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to generate a temporary to test for its type, simply use `decltype`

```
template <class L1, class L2>
auto func3(L1 a, L2 b)
-> std::enable_if_t<
     std::is_same<L1, long>::value &&
     std::is_same<L2, long>::value &&
     std::is_same<decltype(a+b), long>::value, 
     long>
{
  return a + b;
}
```

or with `static_assert`:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void func(T1, T2) = delete;

long func(long a, long b)
{
  static_assert(std::is_same<long,decltype(a+b)>::value,"!!");
  return a+b;
}
```